# Missing template - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates

Here is the structure of the views in my project

```
app
  |
   - views
         | admin
               |
               sidebar.html.erb
         |
         layouts
               |
               admin.html.erb
```

Content of admin.html.erb

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"> <!-- Container begins here -->

<%= render "admin/sidebar" %>

<%= yield %>

    </div> <!-- END Content -->
</div> <!-- END Primary -->


<div class="clear"></div>
</div> <!-- END Container -->

</body>
</html>
```

And I get this error

```
Missing partial admin/sidebar with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/me/blog/app/views"
  * "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
```

I have tried different paths to sidebar but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be "_sidebar.html.erb". Partial file names need to start with '_'.

Comment: Just to be clear, you renamed the file and you still see the same error? I just tried it and it works for me.